# How to add members in category of community site in SharePoint 2016

Tags: permissions, groups, community-site, 2016

How to add members in category of community site  in SharePoint 2016 .
  Actually I want to Set permission category wise, For e.g. I have 2 categories SP2016 and SP2013 with 10 and 15 user respectively. what I want is users of SP2016 not be able to see the discussion happening in the SP2013. Is this Possible... ? Waiting for your suggestions ...